# Combinations of three mutually perpendicular edges of a cube.

Tags: geometry, combinations

I need help in determining the possible combinations of mutually perpendicular edges of a cube, taken three at a time. Two examples are shown in the image attached. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpgko.png)

Comment: There are only three directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cube has $3 \cdot 4$ edges, so each edge can be chosen from one set of four.  That means there are $4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 = 4^3 = 64$ unique combinations.

This assumes that each set of edges is considered as an unordered set, that it does not matter which of the three edges corresponds to $x$, $y$, or $z$.  Each set has $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = 6$ such combinations, so if the order does matter, there are $64 \cdot 6 = 384$ combinations total.

If we consider each set of unordered edges, but exclude those configurations that are just rotated versions of existing sets, we are left with just six unique edge configurations:
[image: Unique cube edge configurations]

(This has been verified with a program that examines all 64 unique combinations, dropping those configurations that are just rotated versions of others, using 90° rotations around each axis.)

---

Here is a Python 3 program, `generate.py`, you can use to generate and/or verify the sets:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Edges are numbered thus:
#   0: (0,0,0)-(0,0,1)  z
#   1: (0,0,0)-(0,1,0)  y
#   2: (0,0,0)-(1,0,0)  x
#   3: (0,0,1)-(0,1,1)  y
#   4: (0,0,1)-(1,0,1)  x
#   5: (0,1,0)-(0,1,1)  z
#   6: (0,1,0)-(1,1,0)  x
#   7: (0,1,1)-(1,1,1)  x
#   8: (1,0,0)-(1,0,1)  z
#   9: (1,0,0)-(1,1,0)  y
#  10: (1,0,1)-(1,1,1)  y
#  11: (1,1,0)-(1,1,1)  z

class Mapping(tuple):

    def __new__(cls, mapping=None):
        d = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ]
        if isinstance(mapping, dict):
            for k,v in mapping.items():
                d[k] = v
        elif mapping is not None:
            raise TypeError("Unsupported mapping type (%s)" % type(mapping))
        return tuple.__new__(cls, d)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return

    def apply(self, mapping):
        d = list(self)
        if isinstance(mapping, dict):
            for k,v in mapping.items():
                d[k] = self[v]
        elif isinstance(mapping, (list, tuple)):
            if len(mapping) != 12:
                raise ValueError("Mapping needs 12 elements, not %d" % len(mapping))
            for k in range(0, 12):
                d[k] = self[mapping[k]]
        else:
            raise TypeError("Unsupported mapping type (%s)" % type(mapping))
        return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, d)

class Triplet(tuple):

    def __new__(cls, *args):
        if len(args) == 1:
            if isinstance(args[0], int):
                args = [ args[0] // 256, (args[0] // 16) & 15, args[0] & 15 ]
            elif isinstance(args[0], (list, tuple)):
                args = args[0]
            else:
                raise TypeError("Invalid triplet definition (%s)" % type(args[0]))
        if len(args) != 3:
            raise ValueError("Triplet needs exactly three arguments, not %d" % len(args))
        return tuple.__new__(cls, sorted(args))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return

    @property
    def key(self):
        return 256*self[0] + 16*self[1] + self[2]

    def apply(self, mapping):
        return tuple.__new__(self.__class__, sorted([mapping[self[0]], mapping[self[1]], mapping[self[2]]]))


def SVG(*triplets):
    w = 8 + 80*len(triplets)
    out = [ '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>\n',
            '<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 %d 136">\n' % w,
            '<rect x="0" y="0" width="%d" height="136" fill="#ffffff" stroke="none"/>\n' % w ]

    def line(x0, x1, y1, x2, y2, t, selected):
        if selected:
            return '<path d="M %d,%d %d,%d" fill="none" stroke="#cc0000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"/>\n' % (x0+x1, y1, x0+x2, y2)
        else:
            return '<path d="M %d,%d %d,%d" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="%s" stroke-linecap="round"/>\n' % (x0+x1, y1, x0+x2, y2, t)

    for i in range(0, len(triplets)):
        x = 80*i
        out.append('<path d="M %d,80 %d,128 %d,104 %d,56 Z" fill="#eff7ff" stroke="none"/>\n' % (x+8, x+32, x+80, x+56))
        out.append('<path d="M %d,32 %d,80 %d,56 %d,8 Z" fill="#dfefff" stroke="none"/>\n' % (x+8, x+8, x+56, x+56))
        out.append('<path d="M %d,56 %d,104 %d,56 %d,8 Z" fill="#bfdfff" stroke="none"/>\n' % (x+56, x+80, x+80, x+56))
        t = Triplet(triplets[i])
        out.append(line(x, 56,8, 56,56, 1, 0 in t))
        if (2 in t):
            out.append('<path d="M %d,80 %d.6,71.2 M %d.8,69.6 %d,56" fill="none" stroke="#cc0000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"/>\n' % (x+8, x+25, x+28, x+56))
        else:
            out.append('<path d="M %d,80 %d,71 M %d.4,69.8 %d,56" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round"/>\n' % (x+8, x+26, x+28, x+56))
        if (1 in t):
            out.append('<path d="M %d,56 %d.2,64.4 M %d.4,66.8 %d,104" stroke="#cc0000" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round"/>\n' % (x+56, x+60, x+61, x+80))
        else:
            out.append('<path d="M %d,56 %d,64 M %d.6,67.2 %d,104" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round"/>\n' % (x+56, x+60, x+61, x+80))
        out.append(line(x,  8,80,  32,128, 2, 9 in t))
        out.append(line(x, 80,104, 32,128, 2, 6 in t))
        out.append(line(x,  8,80,   8,32,  2, 8 in t))
        out.append(line(x, 80,104, 80,56,  2, 5 in t))
        out.append(line(x,  8,32,  56,8,   2, 4 in t))
        out.append(line(x, 56,8,   80,56,  2, 3 in t))
        out.append(line(x, 32,128, 32,80,  1, 11 in t))
        out.append(line(x,  8,32,  32,80,  1, 10 in t))
        out.append(line(x, 32,80,  80,56,  1, 7 in t))

    out.append('</svg>\n')
    return ''.join(out)


class Known:

    def __init__(self, mappings=[]):
        self.known = set()
        self.mappings = mappings

    def __str__(self):
        return "(%d, %d, %d)" % self

    def unique(self, triplet):
        for combination in range(0, 2**len(self.mappings)):
            t = Triplet(triplet)
            for m in range(0, len(self.mappings)):
                if combination & (1 << m):
                    t = t.apply(self.mappings[m])
            k = t.key
            if k in self.known:
                return False
        self.known.add(Triplet(triplet).key)
        return True

    def prefer(self, triplet, scores={}):
        w = [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
        for k,s in scores.items():
            w[k] = s

        best = Triplet(triplet)
        bestscore = 0

        for combination in range(0, 2**len(self.mappings)):
            t = Triplet(triplet)
            for m in range(0, len(self.mappings)):
                if combination & (1 << m):
                    t = t.apply(self.mappings[m])
            score = w[t[0]] + w[t[1]] + w[t[2]]
            if bestscore < score:
                bestscore = score
                best = t

        return best


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import stdout, stderr

    # Edges parallel to axis
    x_edges = ( 2, 4, 6, 7 )
    y_edges = ( 1, 3, 9, 10 )
    z_edges = ( 0, 5, 8, 11 )

    # Each operation is described as a dictionary of old:new edge mappings.
    rotate_x = Mapping({ 0:3,3:5,5:1,1:0, 8:10,10:11,11:9,9:8, 2:4,4:7,7:6,6:2 })
    rotate_y = Mapping({ 1:9,9:10,10:3,3:1, 5:6,6:11,11:7,7:5, 2:8,8:4,4:0,0:2 })
    rotate_z = Mapping({ 2:9,9:6,6:1,1:2, 8:11,11:5,5:0,0:8, 4:10,10:7,7:3,3:4 })
    mirror_x = Mapping({ 0:8,8:0, 3:10,10:3, 5:11,11:5, 1:9,9:1 })
    mirror_y = Mapping({ 8:11,11:8, 2:6,6:2, 4:7,7:4, 0:5,5:0 })
    mirror_z = Mapping({ 2:4,4:2, 1:3,3:1, 9:10,10:9, 6:7,7:6 })

    # To include mirroring or not?
    mirrors = False

    # All known operations:
    if mirrors:
        known = Known([ rotate_x, rotate_x.apply(rotate_x),
                        rotate_y, rotate_y.apply(rotate_y),
                        rotate_z, rotate_z.apply(rotate_z),
                        mirror_x, mirror_y, mirror_z ])
    else:
        known = Known([ rotate_x, rotate_x.apply(rotate_x),
                        rotate_y, rotate_y.apply(rotate_y),
                        rotate_z, rotate_z.apply(rotate_z) ])

    # Unique triplets:
    unique = []

    # Try all 4*4*4 = 64 edge combinations
    for x in x_edges:
        for y in y_edges:
            for z in z_edges:
                t = Triplet(x, y, z)
                if known.unique(t):
                    unique.append(known.prefer(t, { 2:10, 1:10,  # Prefer edges 2 and 1,
                                                    0:8,         # Then edge 0,
                                                    8:6, 5:6,    # Then edges 8 and 5,
                                                    9:4, 6:4,    # Then edges 9, 6, 3, 4,
                                                    3:4, 4:4,    #
                                                    7:1, 10:1, 11:1 }))
    stderr.write("Found %d unique edge triplets:\n" % len(unique))
    for t in unique:
        stderr.write("\t%s\n" % str(t))

    stdout.write(SVG(*unique))
```

Run it using e.g. `python3 generate.py > nomirrors.svg` and it will examine all unique edge triplets, where one edge is parallel to the $x$ axis, one to the $y$ axis, and one to the $z$ axis, excluding rotationally symmetric configurations.  The result is an SVG file (that you can open in for example your browser) describing the above six configurations.

Modify the line `mirrors = False` to `mirrors = True`, and then run e.g. `python3 generate.py > mirrors.svg`, and the result is an SVG file describing the four unique configurations, when both mirrored and rotated configurations are excluded.

`Mapping` is a class which describes how the edges are permuted when an operation is applied to the triplet.  There are six rotations – 90° around the $x$ axis, 180° around the $x$ axis, 90° around the $y$ axis, 180° around the $y$ axis, 90° around the $z$ axis, and 180° around the $z$ axis – so $2^6 = 64$ possible rotation combinations; and three reflections (along the $x$, $y$, or $z$ axis) for $2^3 = 8$ possible reflection combinations.

`Triplet` is a tuple subclass, describing each triplet.  It has a `key` property, which encodes the triplet to a single integer.

`Known` is a class that contains the mappings through which we recognize duplicates (as the `mappings` member).  Its `known` member is an unordered set of known triplet keys.  The `unique(triplet)` method returns `True` if the specified triplet is a new one, adding it to the known set; and `False` if the specified triplet is already known.  The `prefer(triplet, scoreboard)` is a helper function, which "scores" the permutations of the triplet using the specified `scoreboard` dictionary (with unspecified edges getting a score/weight of `1`), returning the permutation of the triplet that yields the highest score.  This is used to select the "nicest" view for each unique edge set.

The `SVG` method returns a string containing an SVG file describing each of the specified triplets, using the same format/visual layout as the image of the six configurations above.

Here is how the program enumerates the edges `0` through `11`:
[image: Edge numbering]
Note that $000$ refers to origin, $100$ to $+x$, $010$ to $+y$, $001$ to $+z$, and so on; these identify the vertices of the cube.

Comment: Thank you. But even in the unordered set, several sets would be still a rotated/ mirrored copies wouldn't it? For example, consider three perpendicular edges that are originated from the a single vertex. This particular relationship can be replicated in all the remaining 7 vertices. How can I filter that out?

Comment: @ijo: Are you *sure* you want to exclude mirrored configurations also?  There are just six rotationally unique sets.  What kind of mirroring would you accept?

Comment: Thank you very much for the solutions, pardon me for mentioning mirroring because it was not exactly mirroring I meant. Out of the six solutions, I see a pattern in 2 and 4 because in here, 2 edges are coinciding and the third edge is offset from the point of coincidence along a single principle direction. In case 3, the third offset of the third edge has components along two principle directions. In case 5 and 6, a similar pattern can be observed amongst them because the red edges are at an offset from a common vertex of the cube, where the offsets are perpendicular amongst each other.

Comment: @ijo: Yes, if we allow any combination of reflection along the $x$, $y$, or $z$ axes, then the number of configurations drops to 4.  I added the Python3 program you can use to explore this to the answer; hopefully you can experiment with it, to see for yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. I could get what I am looking for with the script.

Answer (score 1):

- Pick $1$ edge of the $\color{red}{12}$ possible.
- Your next choice will be from $\color{red} 8$ of the remaining $11$. Pick one.
- There will only be $\color{red} 4$ possible choices for the third edge.

So the number of choices will be $12 \cdot 8 \cdot 4 = 384$

Comment: Thank you very much. I am looking for unique combinations. The permutations within a particular set of perpendicular edges does not matter.